# replace a string in all occurence using regular expression

Tags: regex

Hi I want to replace [[$Title]] with shanmugam in all occurence. here is my code.

```
    <script>
    emailContents = '[[FirstName]] [[LastName]] watched "AccelaCast Program" and sent you the following comment and link:[[iaf_message/5]][[#if iaf_message/6 No]]http://webcasts.advanstar.com/acc/iaf/1/[[$PROGRAMID]]/Clicking the URL above will take you to the webcast: "[[$Title]]" [[#else]]http://webcasts.advanstar.com/acc/iaf/1/[[$PROGRAMID]]/?_IAFSegment=[[$SEGMENT]]&_IAFTime=[[$posmmss]]Clicking the URL above will take you to the webcast "[[$Title]]" at the point in the program that [[/User/FirstName]] thought would be most relevant to you.[[#endif]]Message from Advanstar Communications[Sender IP: [[$IP]]] If you believe you have received this email in error, or for customer service at Accela Communications, please send a message to mailto:support.getinfoadvanstar.com Macros program id:    [[$programid]] pos: [[$pos]] segment: [[$segment]] pos minutes sec: [[$posmmss]] Title: [[$title]] ip: [[$ip]] link: [[#link http://getinfo2.advanstar.com/ASP/main.jsp Getinfo  Getinfo]] Image: [[#img http://getinfo2.advanstar.com/ASP/images/AdvanstarProgram175x37.jpg]] Eval#eval #3.2 floor :[[#eval #3.2 floor ]]'
    emailContents = emailContents.replace(/\[\[$Title\]\]/g,'shanmugam');
    console.log(emailContents);
</script>
```

Pleae help me. .

Comment: You're not even specifying the language you use...

Comment: While the `<script>` tag makes it *easier* to guess the language, you still haven't tagged the question with the right language, or written something clear like "I have the following JavaScript code". It is also a good idea to explain clearly what does happen with the current code, as well as what you wanted to happen; in this case, I'm guessing the result is "the string stays the same". Meanwhile, you have mentioned "case insensitive" in comments below, but this is not in the question; try not to leave details like this out when you write the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code would replace the `[[FIRSTNAME]]` with shanmugam,

```
emailContents = emailContents.replace(/\[\[FirstName\]\]/g,'shanmugam');
```

In regex `[]` are special characters(which means character class), to represent a literal `[]` symbols, you need to escape it.

If you wanna case insensitive  replace of `$Title`, then run the below,

```
emailContents = emailContents.replace(/\[\[\$Title\]\]/gi,'shanmugam');
```

`$` in regex has a special meaning(represents the end of a line). To represent a literal `$`, you need to escape it.

Comment: "Try this" followed by code, even correct, does not make a good answer. *Please explain your answer.*

Comment: @Avinash Raj  If i want to replace [[$Title]] with case insensitive for same exmaple , how can i do ??

Comment: @Shanmugam Please take a moment to work out what question(s) you want to ask, tell us what programming language you're using rather than making us guess, and ask each question clearly on a separate page. This site is not designed to work like a discussion forum.

Comment: then try `emailContents = emailContents.replace(/\[\[\$Title\]\]/g,'shanmugam');`

Comment: if you wanns case insensitive replace then try `emailContents = emailContents.replace(/\[\[\$Title\]\]/gi,'shanmugam');`